# RDWebAccess Part in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tsweb

I have got the WebAccessPart working in Sharepoint as a way for out users to run our business apps. I would like to be able to set the value of both check boxes to be true by default (the optimize lan experience and using private computer), and also hide them so the user never has to deal with them.

I have managed to hide them by editing the XML for the web part and adding these keys:

False
False

This does the job of hiding them, but i cant find a way to set the values to true. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: I think you will have better luck with your question at the [SharePoint Stack Exchange.](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by editing the master page and adding some Javascript in so that after it loaded it checked the item